# Regex to find http and .html

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to find links in the following format:

```
http://subdomain.subdomain.domain.tld/subfolder/randomstring.html
```

Basically, I need a regex that looks for `http://` and stops looking when it finds `.html`. Everything in between shouldn't matter. I.e., more/less subdomains, variable TLD and variable folder.

Is this possible?

```
((http://)?=(.html))
```

What I've got so far (not functional) is this. I'm really not familiar with the look-ahead assertion so I might be on the wrong track.

Anyways, any help is going to be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Sjoerd: or more precisely: what regex kind? In C++0x you have different kinds of regexes available (ECMAScript, egrep, grep, etc.)

Comment: I'll be implementing it in Python.

Comment: @Benoit...I'm ashamed to admit I don't know. I think its grep. My guide has been the Regex Cheat Sheet from addedbytes.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look ahead? You only need a non-greedy match everything.

```
/http:\/\/.*?\.html/
```

Comment: `.*` matches anything, greedily. That is, it will match as much as possible. It will match the http of the first link right up to the .html of the last link. If you want to stop matching as soon as .html is found, thus matching as little as possible, you need to be ungreedy. `.*?` matches anything, without being greedy.

Comment: Which is what I have in that answer.

Comment: I believe this worked! I had to remove the initial/final "/" to test it in Kiki but it seems to find all the appropriate links and none of the wrong ones. Thanks! Will accept when timer allows.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like: `/http:\/\/[^<>\s]+?\.html/`

Can be enhanced, but at least won't match stuff like:

`http://something.com/ has a lot of .html files`

Comment: I can certainly appreciate that. However, the nature of this site makes it highly unlikely. I do appreciate the answer though. +

Comment: I always like to be as careful as possible. In many cases you can't predict what will become of your code or the site two maintainers later ;)